# How to fix "Moved TemporarilyMoved Temporarily The document has moved here"

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, newsfeed, rss

I am getting this error . I have embedded google RSS feed on my website. it was working fine but now it gives me this annoying error saying

> "Moved TemporarilyMoved Temporarily The document has moved here."

How do I fix it ?

this is the [URL](http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&hl=en&q=Ralf%20Speth%20Jaguar%20Land%20Range%20Rover%20Europe%20Manufacturing%20Union&as_qdr=y&output=rss&ndplr=1) I am using when I open it in a browser, it works fine but when I embed it in a web part it displays the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this on a 2013 site and solved it by updating the URL of the RSS feed.

The current URL began with `http`, and updated URL now begins with `https`.